# Undo files disappear from desktop

Tags: video, recovery

I cut video files from my SD card and paste it into computer desktop. Later, I accidentally press Ctrl z , due to which fie disappear from desktop. No I have no files on desktop and not in my SD card.

How can I get back my video files

Comment: This is not a programming question. Ask on SuperUser instead

Comment: @ADyson ok sorry

Answer (score -2):

If you've already checked the Recycle Bin and tried Ctrl-Y to redo, you could also try using a file recovery software system. There are plenty online available to install.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).